# How to remove Byte Order Mark in python

Tags: python, byte-order-mark

This question is related to a recent change to the Stack Overflow API that I reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235000/186281). In that question, I received a [response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235021/186281) that seems like it'd work, but in practice I'm unable to make it work.

This is my code

```
import requests
import json
url="https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites/?filter=%21%2AL1%2AAY-85YllAr2%29&pagesize=1&page=1"
response = requests.get(url)
response.text
```

This outputs

```
u'\ufeff{"items":[{"site_state":"normal","api_site_parameter":"stackoverflow","name":"Stack Overflow"}],"has_more":true,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":294}'
```

The leading `u'\ufeff` means that if I do `response.json()` I get a `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

The suggestion I was provided was to use `decode('utf-8-sig')`. However, I can't seem to get this work work either:

Try 1:

```
response.text.decode('utf-8-sig')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Try 2:

```
json.loads(response.text).decode('utf-8-sig')
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What is the appropriate way to remove the leading `u'\ufeff`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`response.text` is a Unicode object, i. e. it already has been decoded, so you can't decode it again.

What you need to do is tell the `response` object which encoding it should use:

```
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = "utf-8-sig"
response.text
```

See the [docs for more background info](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content).